# A simple bash program that prints the third character of a string, that uses [[ ]] (compare to method)

Tags: bash

Unfortunately i tried this and it doesn't work, i must use the [[ ]]

```
read input

for i in input
do      
   if [[ i =    "$input" ]]
   then    
    echo "i"
   fi      
done
```

when I run this nothing happens, it only reads my input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
if [[ i =    "$input" ]]
```

should be:

```
if [[ "$i" = "$input" ]]
```

OR:

```
if [[ "$i" == "$input" ]]
```

PS: Same thing for `input` also.

Remember that variables in shell are accessed with `$` prefix.

May be you can re-factor your script to this:

```
read input
for i in $input
do      
   [[ "$i" == "something" ]] && echo "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I think when you use only numbers you can also try:

```
for i in input
do      
   if [[ $i  -eq  "$input" ]]
   then    
    echo "$i"
   fi      
done
```